# "if/else" condition misbehaving inside click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I am having trauble with if else condition inside a click event of jquery. I have set a variable. i want to show an alert with the message "business", when the variable- dropdown is "Business". Other wise the alert will show "Animales". But the following code doesnt check for the variable. It just triggering the first alert which is "animales" everytime. What I am doing wrong?

```js
$('.item').click(function(){
        var dropValue = "Buisness";
        
         if (dropValue = "Animals"){
             alert('animals');
         }else if(dropValue = "Business"){
             alert("business");
         }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="item">Click me</button>
```

Comment: `= vs ==`......

Comment: = is assignment, == is test for equality

Comment: closing as typo

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators?v=control

Comment: One more: `"Buisness" != "Business"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will work:

```js
$('.item').click(function(){
        var dropValue = "Business";
         if (dropValue == "Animals"){
             alert('animals');
         }else if(dropValue == "Business"){
             alert("business");
         }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="item">Click me</button>
```

**REMEMBER**

**=** is used to assign a value.

**==** is used to check the value.

also your spelling of business is incorrect in

`var dropValue = "Buisness";`

Comment: Really. Answering this?

Comment: @mplungjan  I agree it is weird but the OP needs to know this, except the typo part.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators?v=control is a good link

Comment: Ah, I missed the OTHER typo ;)

Comment: Thanks. I had lost my mind.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `==` not `=`

```
if (dropValue == "Animals")
....
else if(dropValue == "Business")
...
```

Comment: And therefore not worth answering

Comment: @mplungjan , lol thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.item').click(function() {
  var dropValue = "Business";
  if (dropValue == "Animals") {
    alert('animals');
  } else if (dropValue == "Business") {
    alert("business");
  }
});
```

"Buisness" should be *"Business*" and use `==`(comparison operator) or even better `===`(Strict comparison) instead of `=` as `=` is assignment operator not comparison operator.

Comment: Matter of typos ain't it ? We have option to "flag" such question.. :(

Comment: @Rayon - only with enough rep

Comment: @mplungjan - Yeah! I am disappointed that we have 4 answers for this question and all contributors are from my _country_ :( :(

Comment: @Rayon - yeah, it's hard to answer questions fast enough. Sometimes even harder for me because I often reformat the question before answering, losing time...

Comment: @mplungjan - Well, I think you are investing your time for a purpose and it is definitely helping other developers and future visitors to have better understanding of available content...

Comment: @Rayon indeed. I am here to help. The rep is a side-effect :)

Comment: @Rayon maybe it's a typo but if there is a mistake in a code then it doesn't work.